# InnerHTML at beginning of vbscript function does not take effect immediately

Tags: dom, vbscript, innerhtml, hta

I'm using vbscript within a hta. file to write data to a .docx file. I want some kind of "status monitor" to tell the user when the process has started, when the file has been saved and so on...
Writing to the file works fine, but whatever I do, innerHTML or any DOM change is taking effect way after the file has been saved. After clicking the button it's kind of frozen. I would have supposed the code is executed line by line, but apparently it's not- the question is why and what to do?

VBScript:

```
        Function TextToWord
        Document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Start writing to doc..."

        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

        objWord.Visible = False
        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("file.docx")

        Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Name").Range
        objRange.Text = "Some Text..."

        objDoc.SaveAs("newfile.docx")
        objDoc.Close

        End Function
```

HTML/HTA:

```
        <button class="myButton" onClick="TextToWord()">Word Dokument erstellen</button>
        <div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: What happens if you use `document.getElementById("status").innerText = "Start writing to doc..."` ?  If the same thing occurs, can you use `<div id="status" style="display:none">Start writing to doc...</div>` with `document.getElementById("status").style.display = "block"` instead?

Comment: I've tried that before. It's the same result... However e.g. msgBox is working; I've tried that out before, it's even updating the innerHTML if I leave the code in place. So it's got to be something with the DOM...